# How to specify the target path for some files in an Android APK?

Tags: android, android-manifest, android-install-apk

Is there a way to specify that a specific file in my application project should be installed on the shared area of an SD card, while the rest goes to the internal phone storage?

Thanks
Jamil

Answer (score 0, accepted):

no that is not really possible in my opinion

Comment: but you can do it, if you download the file afterwards. :)

Answer (score 0):

I used to do the same thing but failed.
The only thing you can do is to specify a prefered intall location in the manifest.

[DOC](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/manifest-element.html#install)

Comment: Michael, I want to specify the the exact target folder for one file rather than the whole APK conten